# Binomial-coefficients if, k, m, n natural numbers and k \leq n the result of

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

If $k, m, n$, are natural numbers and $k \leq n$ What is:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{m}\frac{k\binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{k}}{(r+k)\binom{m+n}{r+k}}$$

Comment: I wish there are someone help me

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Maths.SE, have you tried anything yet? We would be able to help you more if you showed what you tried

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question short timpe ago ?

Comment: yeah, can you answer it ?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\Large\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^{m}\frac{\color{green}k\binom{m}{r}\color{green}{\binom{n}{k}}}{\color{blue}{(r+k)\binom{m+n}{r+k}}}
&=\frac{\color{green}{n } }{\color{blue}{m+n}} \sum_{r=0}^{m}\frac{\binom mr\color{green}{\binom {n-1} {k-1}}}{\color{blue}{\binom {m+n-1}{r+k-1}}}\\\\
&=\frac{n}{m+n} \cdot \frac{m+n}{n}\\\\
&=1\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

NB: the proof above uses the identity
$$\sum_{r=0}^m \large\frac{\binom mr\binom ab}{\binom {m+a}{r+b}}=\frac{m+a+1}{a+1}$$ 
where $a=n-1, b=k-1$. The derivation of this is given below.

Note that 
$$\begin{align} 
\binom{m+a}m\binom m{r+b}&=\color{purple}{\binom {m+a}{r+b}}\binom {m+a-r-b}{m-r-b}\\\\
\Rightarrow \color{purple}{\binom {m+a}{r+b}}&=\large\frac{\binom{m+a}m\binom m{r+b}}{\binom {m+a-r-b}{m-r-b}}
=\color{purple}{\frac{\binom{m+a}a\binom m{r+b}}{\binom {m+a-r-b}a}}\\\\
\sum_{r=0}^{m}\large\frac{\binom mr\binom ab}{\color{purple}{\binom {m+a}{r+b}}}
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom mr \binom ab\large\color{purple}{\frac{\binom {m+a-r-b}a}{\binom{m+a}a\binom m{r+b}}}\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^m\large\frac{\binom m{m-r}\color{orange}{\binom {m+a-r-b}{a}\binom a{a-b}}}{\binom m{r+b}}\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^m\large\frac{\binom m{m-r}\color{orange}{\binom {m+a-r-b}{a-b}\binom {m-r}b}}{\binom m{r+b}}\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^m\large\frac{\color{red}{\binom m{m-r}\binom {m-r}{m-r-b}}\binom {m+a-r-b}{a-b}}{\binom m{r+b}}\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^m\large\frac{\color{red}{\binom m{r+b}\binom {r+b}{b}}\binom {m+a-r-b}{a-b}}{\binom m{r+b}}\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^m\binom {b+r}{b}\binom {m+a-b-r}{a-b}\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\binom {b+(m+a-b)+1}{b-b+(m+a-b)-(a-b)}\quad \text{(see ** below)}\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\binom {m+a+1}m\\
&=\binom {m+a}a^{-1}\binom {m+a+1}{a+1}\\
&=\frac{m+a+1}{a+1}\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

** makes use of the summation identity
$$\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {A+r}B \binom {C-r}D=\binom {A+C+1}{A-B+C-D}$$
where $A=b, B=b, C=m+a-b, D=a-b$.

The identity can be proven as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {A+r}B \binom {C-r}D
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom {A+r}{A+r-B}\binom {C-r}{C-r-D}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^{A+r-B+C-r-D}\binom {-B-1}{A+r-B}\binom {-D-1}{C-r-D}\\
&=(-1)^{A-B+C-D}\binom{-B-D-2}{A-B+C-D}\quad \text{(using Vandermonde)}\\
&=(-1)^{2(A-B+C-D)}\binom{A+C+1}{A-B+C-D}\\
&=\binom{A+C+1}{A-B+C-D}\qquad \blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you continue it ?

Comment: Yes, it's been completed.

Comment: Edited to provide greater detail.

Comment: Many thanks for the added detail; both identities were new to me.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - You're welcome! I didn't know them too but arrived at the result using a numerical example, then set about deriving the proof!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different answer to this nice question.

> We observe:
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{r=0}^{m}&\frac{k\binom{m}{r}\binom{n}{k}}{(r+k)\binom{m+n}{r+k}}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{m}\frac{m!}{r!(m-r)!}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}\frac{(r+k-1)!(m+n-r-k)!}{(m+n)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{m!n!}{(m+n)!}\sum_{r=0}^{m}\frac{(r+k-1)!}{r!(k-1)!}\frac{(m+n-r-k)!}{(m-r)!(n-k)!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{m+n}{m}^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom{r+k-1}{r}\binom{m-r+n-k}{m-r}\tag{4}\\
> &=\binom{m+n}{m}^{-1}\sum_{r=0}^{m}\binom{-k}{r}(-1)^r\binom{-(n-k+1)}{m-r}(-1)^{m-r}\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{m+n}{m}^{-1}(-1)^m\binom{-(n+1)}{m}\tag{6}\\
> &=\binom{m+n}{m}^{-1}\binom{m+n}{m}\tag{7}\\
> &=1\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment*:

- (2) In order to get a better overview we write all factorials explicitely and cancel the factors $k$ and $r+k$.
- (3) We factor out some factorials which do not depend on the index $r$ and we reorder the factorials since we want to write them as binomial coefficients to simplify further calculations.
- (4) Just a rewrite of (3) with the help of binomial coefficients. Observe that (4) and (1) look quite different although they are equal.

> So, here we have a nice example underpinning the following remark by D.E. Knuth in section 5.5 *Hypergeometric functions* in [Concrete Mathematics](http://unina.stidue.net/Complementi%20di%20Analisi%20Matematica/Materiale/Concrete%20Mathematics.pdf):
>
> *Binomial coefficients* are like **chameleons**, changing their appearance easily.

- (5) We apply the following identity twice (see e.g. Vol 1, (1.6) in H.W. Goulds [Table of binomial identities](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.1.PDF))

\begin{align*}
\binom{-k}{r}=\binom{k+r-1}{k}(-1)^k\tag{8}
\end{align*}

- (6) We use the [Vandermonde identity](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_Identity)

\begin{align*}
\sum_{r}\binom{a}{r}\binom{b}{m-r}=\binom{a+b}{m}\qquad\qquad a,b\in \mathbb{R},m\in \mathbb{Z}\tag{9}
\end{align*}

- (7) Here we use again identity (8)

> *Summary:* The essence of this calculation is finding a convenient representation of the *Vandermonde identity*. (1) is a more or less complicated representation of it with the binomial coefficient of the RHS of (9) as reciprocal factor on the LHS.

---

A **combinatorial interpretation** of (1) is essentially that for the *Vandermonde identity* (9). We could argue e.g. in terms of *lattice pathes* on a rectangular grid:

> We consider pathes containing only $(1,0)$-steps in $x$-direction and $(0,1)$-steps in $y$-direction. The expression
>
> $$\binom{a+b}{m}$$
>
> gives the *number of all pathes* of length $a+b$ from $(0,0)$ to $(m,a+b-m)$ containing exactly $m$ $(1,0)$ steps in $x$-direction. The sum
>
> $$\sum_{r}\binom{a}{r}\binom{b}{m-r}$$
>
> *partitions* these pathes in those of length $a$ with exactly $r$ $(0,1)$-steps in $x$-direction times the number of pathes of length $b$ with exactly $m-r$ $(0,1)$-steps in $x$-direction.

Answer (score -4):

$$\sum_{r=0}^m \frac{k \binom{m}{r} \binom{n}{k}}{(r+k) \binom{m+n}{r+k}}=\sum_{r=0}^m \frac{k \frac{m!}{r!(m-r)!} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}{(r+k) \frac{(m+n)!}{(r+k)!(m+n-r-k)!}}$$

Continue making calculations.

Comment: Can you continue